# How to get syscall number (without compiling)?

Tags: java, linux, system-calls

I am trying to invoke syscalls from Java like in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1683/120349). (Specifically, `mount`.) The answer says to invoke `syscall`.

Is there a way to get the syscall number programmatically?

Assuming no and I have to hard-code it or dig for it in include files, could you answer:

- On Linux, What is the difference between `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h` (`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd` on Ubuntu x86_64) and `/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h`? What is `asm-generic` and why does it have different values?
- Why does linux-arm64 only have `asm-generic`?
- Is there a better way to call `mount`? What library is it in?
- What about MacOS and BSD?

Comment: Have you considered just calling out to `/usr/bin/mount`? That would likely be much less effort to set up and maintain as well as more portable.

Comment: @TooTea I don’t think I can. I’m trying to implement FUSE (without libfuse), and `mount -t fuse` wants to call an executable instead of talking to the kernel.

Comment: What about MacOS and BSD? The syscall number for mount() and its parameters differ between Linux and BSD.

Comment: Why not define and call `mount()` directly? You can do that too, via `c.mount(...)`, if you define it in the CStdLib interface. But it would be far simpler and lighter-weight to use a C executable. About 10 lines of C code, and no JVM.